# Lambda function through API gateway fails due to Malformed Lambda proxy response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

for some reason my AWS lambda returns a 502 error no matter how i change my response.

> Sun Mar 25 03:39:12 UTC 2018 : Endpoint response body before
>   transformations:
>   {"status":200,"body":"{\"Items\":[],\"Count\":0,\"ScannedCount\":1}","isBase64Encoded":false,"headers":{"content-type":"application/json"}}

I have made sure to stringify my body and add the status, headers, and isBase64Encodeded properties. I have tried varying the headers and making them empty as well.

Why do i get this error?

here is the lambda code:

```
    var response = {
        status : 200,
        body : JSON.stringify(data),
        isBase64Encoded : false,
        headers : {"content-type" : "application/json"}
    }

    console.log(response)

    callback(null, response);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

API Gateway expects `statusCode`, not `status`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format